# How to display the content of an Objective-C array when html button gets clicked in UIWebview.

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have a array in the Objective-C source.

I have to display the contents of array on onclick of a button in Html or Javascript, how to link the Html file in objective C in xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the uiwebview to display the html content in objective-c

Create a webview in xib and connect it to IBoutlet UIWebView *web;
Then write this code wherever you want.And the file should be in the resources folder

```
 NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"filename"] ofType:@"html"];   
   NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1];
   NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
   [web loadRequest:request1];
```